# A Russian translation for "privacy"

Tags: лексикон, перевод

How would you translate `privacy` into Russian?

> May I have some privacy?
>
> I care about my privacy.

Comment: `уединение`, `частная жизнь`, `конфиденциальность` http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/ru/Translate/en-ru/privacy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think we have a case of a concept not really present in the Russian linguistic world image. One can speculate if the privacy has not really been valued until recently, but that's beyond the point.

- *Конфиденциальность* can be used in more formal cases, like in the terms of use of a website, for example. It refers to the information collected about a person (think Facebook).
- *Частная жизнь* (as in *неприкосновенность частной жизни*) is again a law-term, usually referring to the actual physical privacy.
- For colloquial usage, what @Dima suggests is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 13):

AFIK, there is no good translation. Lately, I have been encountering the word `приватность`, but I don't think it is standard.

If you have to translate it, you have to reword it taking the context into account.  For example, you might translate `Can you give us some privacy?` as `Не могли бы вы оставить нас одних?`  Or you might translate `I value my privacy.` as `Я не люблю когда лезут в мои дела.`

Answer (score 7):

I would guess:

- конфиденциальность
- частная жизнь
- неприкосновенность частной жизни
- секретность
- уединенность, уединение
- тайна
- личное дело
- интимная сторона личной жизни
- интимная сфера
- прайвеси

Comment: прайвеси is about as awkward as эксклюзивный. :)

Comment: @Dima, that is an Easter egg for you

Comment: And I completely agree with the awkwardness of the word прайвеси... No one in the right mind would use the word :)

Comment: When to use what? :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best matches is word *покой*, although  "*оставьте меня в покое*" means rather 'leave me alone' than 'can I have some privаcy'. The examples suggested for translation would become:

Не могли бы Вы оставить меня в покое?

Мне небезразличен мой покой.

Answer (score 0):

In the sphere of IT the direct imporation of this word is also used:

> Приватность в интернете
>
> Настройки приватности

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you should read this article:

- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Персональные_данные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

> How would you translate privacy into Russian?

"Приватность". The IT sphere is the first in line of borrowing of words from another languages.